# Jooq how to deal with mysql default?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I'm trying to use a field with a default value but I have a problem with jooq, the default value is not used and the value of the object's field is still null.

How can I make JOOQ use the default value from my table ?

This is the SQL of my declaration :

```
`Status tinyint (1) DEFAULT 0`
```

Comment: Unless you force jooq refetch the object from database I don't see how it is possible. I use Hibernate and usually I duplicate that part of the mapping by putting the default value within the object model too.

Comment: Can you share your jooq query as well? If you want sql to use the default value, then just don't include it in the insert statement.

Comment: *"the default value is not used and the value of the object's field is still null."* What do you mean by this? Could you explain: 1) What is your jOOQ code, 2) what is your expected behaviour.

Comment: A field of the user table is defined as follows:
`Status tinyint (1) DEFAULT 0`

My Java code is as follows:
I want to add a new user (user), user field is a field field, the default value is 0, I used jooq when this is: insert (user); I did not give the user assignment.
I want to save the database after the user has a default value of 0